# python file reading loop issue

Tags: python

I got an issue while trying to pick up data from txt file. Solution is going to be simple for sure, but anyways i think i need a little bit of your help.
For now it prints like that '123 123456', but i want to print it like '123 456', any ideas?

INPUT

```
asd
ear
hello
hello
hello
rea
ear
world
world
rea
zxczxc
```

CODE

```
check = False
data = ''
start = 'ear'
end = 'rea'

with open('bear.txt', 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines()
    for i,x in enumerate(lines):
        if start in x:
            check = True
        if check:
            data += str(x)
        if end in x:
            check = False
            print(data)
            print(i)
```

OUTPUT

```
ear
hello
hello
hello
rea

5
ear
hello
hello
hello
rea
ear
world
world
rea

9
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
ear
hello
hello
hello
rea

5
ear
world
world
rea

4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
check = False
data = ''
start = 'ear'
end = 'rea'

with open('bear.txt', 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines()
    for x in lines:
        if start in x:
            check = True
        if check:
            data += str(x)
        if end in x:
            check = False
            print(data)

            # Count of data that split by `\n`
            # However, there is one extra `\n` so minus 1.
            print(len(data.split("\n")) - 1)

            # If it is not initialized, the contents will remain intact
            data = ''
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

- you need to reinitialize `data`

```
check = False
data = ''
start = 'ear'
end = 'rea'

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines()
    for i,x in enumerate(lines):
        if start in x:
            check = True
        if check:
            data += str(x)
        if end in x:
            check = False
            print(data)
            print(i)
            data = ''
```

Output:

```
ear
hello
hello
hello
rea

5
ear
world
world
rea

9
```

- **NOTE**: This will not print 4. From the output it looks like you want to print the length of data. For that part your logic is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i needed, to reinitialize my data. You helped a lot my man

Comment: If answer helped you can click tick on answer that worked for you.